# Cant get script to defer

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, deferred-loading

I have the following script which generates about 4000 lines of code on my website:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
var makemods2 = new Array;
<?php
$i = 0;
foreach ($makemods2 as $k=>$items) {
foreach ($items as $v) {
echo "makemods2[".$i++."] = new Array( '$k','".addslashes( $v->value )."','".addslashes( $v->text )."' );\n\t\t";
}
}
?>
//-->
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

This is really heavy on pageload, so of course I want to defer parsing. However since it is not external than I cannot use defer=defer.

I also read the tips from Google that suggest a syntax like this, which I do not know how to write for the above code:

```
<script language="javascript">
var node2 = document.createElement('script');
node2.type = 'text/javascript';
node2.async = true;
function switchDynaList2(listname,source,key,orig_key,orig_val){var list=eval("document.moduleForm."+listname);for(i in list.options.length){list.options[i]=null}i=0;for(x in source){if(source[x][0]==key){opt=new Option;opt.value=source[x][1];opt.text=source[x][2];if(orig_key==key&&orig_val==opt.value||i==0){opt.selected=true}list.options[i++]=opt}}list.length=i}
</script>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is your end goal here? Maybe you could use AJAX to show bits of information at a time instead of dumping the entire thing into the page?

Comment: You're never assigning content to `node2`. What do you expect of it?

Comment: the end goal is at this site: http://xn--bdbasen-exa.com/

You can see the dropdowns in the left hand side. We are loading about 400 boat makes and 4000 models.

I am not a whiz at ajax, I had a developer do it, but when asking him know he is not able to do it.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is the way to go but as you seem to want to avoid that I would suggest:

**Approach 1**

Back in the day before AJAX and such handling of page load states, we used to put script tags at the end of the body tag. This would allow the body contents to be parsed, without being delayed by the script execution. Then all you need to do is default your dropdowns to disabled and enable them when the script finishes executing.

**Note:**

- Some styling issues may occur.
- This approach to some is considered deprecated.

**Approach 2**

Move the PHP code into it's own page and include the script using the src attribute of the script tag. You can then use defer attribute on the script tag.

Comment: Putting javascript at the end of the body tag is still very much in use. In fact it's still highly recommended to do so.

Comment: It is difficult for me to put it at the bottom of the page as it is a module being called in Joomla.

Comment: To put it into PHP how should i structure that page. If anybody is available to do some freelancing on this task then please PM me...

Comment: does it become like this in js:


'var makemods2 = new Array;'
'document.write("<?php $i = 0; foreach ($makemods2 as $k=>$items) { ?>");'
'document.write("<?php foreach ($items as $v) { ?>");'
'document.write("<?php echo makemods2[$i++] ?>");'
'document.write("<?php = new Array( $k, addslashes( $v->value ) ?>");'
'document.write("<?php ','.addslashes( $v->text ).' );\n\t\t ?>");'
'document.write("<?php } } ?>");'